# I am unable to fetch the data from an Array[Object{}]. Especially unable to iterate individually using for loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to extract the data from API individually, how to pull out the data from Array?

```
let {Array}=jsonData
```

```
fetch("https://apis.ccbp.in/city-bikes?bike_name" + search, options)
.then(function(response){ 
 return response.json();
})
.then(function(jsonData){
let {Array}=jsonData

console.log(Array)
console.log(jsonData)
})
```

output - undefined

output-

> Array [Object {}]
> 0: Object {city: "Moscow", id: "velobike-mosco.

Comment: The `Array` does not mean there is a key called that, so you can't destructure it (the `let {key}=obj` syntax. It means that the data returned *is* an array. What happens when you use a for loop to iterate through it?

Comment: The object conatins the bunch of data looks like this    Object {city: "Moscow", id: "velobike-mosco...
city: "Moscow"
id: "velobike-moscow"
name: "Velobike"            . so i want to iterate each of them and get it prints on the div class in html       seacrhResults.textContent=city .......

Answer (score 1):

Yeah so just loop over it with a for loop?

```js
fetch("https://apis.ccbp.in/city-bikes?bike_name")
.then(function(response){ 
 return response.json();
})
.then(res => {
  for (const entry of res) {
    let {city, id, name} = entry;
    
    console.log(city, id, name);
    // then you can do whatever you'd like
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting data based on the query parameters called bike_name, you need to use template literal string for using a variable in the string. Use the arrow functions instead of traditional functions in the then() promise chain. The below code will help you.

```
 fetch(`https://apis.ccbp.in/city-bikes?bike_name=${value}`,{method:'GET',headers:{}})
.then((response)=>{ 
 return response.json();
})
.then((jsonData){
console.log(jsonData)'
})
```